# respond error of .setup.sh

Tags: ros, setup.sh, setup.bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

according to the Ros installing tutorials

**Installing and Configuring Your ROS Environment**
when i type $ .setup.sh it gives me the error of 
"bash: setup.sh: No such file or directory"
and when i type $ source  ~/setup.sh
it again give me the same error what is the issue.kindly help me out

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27969/respond-error-of-.setup.sh/) by [danish](https://answers.ros.org/users/1766/danish/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

setup.sh will be in different places depending on how you installed ROS. If you're on Ubuntu and used apt-based install, it will be in /opt/ros/[version]/. If you did a source-based install using rosinstall, it will be in whatever directory you passed in as the first argument to rosinstall (~/ros is what's frequently used in the examples).

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [danish](https://answers.ros.org/users/1766/danish/) on 2012-02-20**:
for ROS_PACKAGE_PATH  i have tp paste the same command as it is or have to make same changes  "export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/user/ros/ros-pkg:/another/path"